# How to Get or Record the ID of a element with the current focus for later retrieval using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What i want is to save the html values and then display it with the previous function when the button called previous is clicked.
However what i forgot to think about is that `document.getElementById('id')` doesn't return a value, it returns something like **[object HTMLElement]**.

How do i get the value of the id?

```
var namevalue1 = document.getElementById('name');
var imagetitlevalue1 = document.getElementById('imagetitle');
var locationvalue1=document.getElementById('location') ;
var similaritiesvalue1 = document.getElementById('similarities');
var typevalue1 = document.getElementById('type');
var costvalue1 = document.getElementById('cost');
var datevalue1 = document.getElementById('date');
var pictureidvalue1 = document.getElementById('pictureid');


function previous()
{
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = namevalue1;
    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = locationvalue1;
    document.getElementById('similarities').innerHTML = similaritiesvalue1;
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = typevalue1;
    document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = costvalue1;
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = datevalue1;
    document.getElementById('pictureid').src = pictureidvalue1;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to extract from the HTML. In particular the phrase "html values" is not clear. Can you post some HTML and explain what you are trying to get out?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of element, if you want a textual representation of the HTML within the element, use `innerHTML`

```
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML
```

If you only want the text within the element and its descendants use `textContent`

```
 document.getElementById("id").textContent
```

Finally if you're working with <input> elements you could use `value`

```
 document.getElementById("id").value
```