# How to use parameters from another function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get actual HTML values using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674095/get-actual-html-values-using-javascript)

so i have two problems here.  let me explain what i am trying to do first.  I have a page that has values that change on it, however i want to grab the values before they change, keep them, and then once a button is pushed, change the html to the original html.  Now first of all my biggest problem is that when i try to uncomment the initial2 function, it just doesnt work.  it brings me to the webpage then for some reason the html url tries to change and it says it can not find the page.  the second, and more understandable problem for me, is that the function previousaccept i cant get to use the values from the previousnames function.

```
function previousnames()
{
name= document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
imagetitle= document.getElementById('imagetitle').innerHTML;
location=document.getElementById('location').innerHTML;
similarities = document.getElementById('similarities').innerHTML;
type = document.getElementById('type').innerHTML;
cost = document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML;
date = document.getElementById('date').innerHTML;
pictureid = document.getElementById('pictureid').src;
}

function previousaccept(name,imagetitle,location,similarities,value,type,cost,date,pictureid)
{
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = location;
document.getElementById('similarities').innerHTML = similarities;
document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = type;
document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = cost;
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
window.alert(pictureid);
document.getElementById('pictureid').src = pictureid;
}
window.onload=initial();
function initial()
{
myvalues;
previousnames;
}

/*
function initial2()
{
myvalues;
previousnames();
}*/
```

Comment: there are several problems with your code: `myvalues` is used but has not been defined anywhere. `previousnames` is used the first time without being followed by `()`, so it won't do anything. You define but don't use the function `previousaccept`. If you want to use global variables then you don't need to pass them as parameters to the function `previousaccept`, so could just define it as `function previousaccept()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `location` (which is [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)), then the browser will go to a new web page.  That's what you're doing in the `previousnames()` function with this line:

```
location=document.getElementById('location').innerHTML;
```

If you're trying to have a global variable named `location`, then give it a different name that isn't already used by the browser.

Also, you should explicitly declare any global variables you intend to use outside of your functions rather than use implicitly declared variables like you are which makes your code very prone to errors.

Comment: sweet thanks changed every location to locationq now it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. The key is to make sure that the scope of the variables you are trying to store is such that the functions have access to them all. I do this by defining an empty object `dataStore` at the start of the `onload` function, and also defining the 2 other functions *within* the onload function. Putting all the stored data in a single object is convenient and avoids naming problems (such as the window.location problem noted by the previous answer.)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var dataStore = {};

    function getInitialData() {
        dataStore = {
            name: document.getElementById('name').innerHTML,
            imagetitle: document.getElementById('imagetitle').innerHTML,
            // and so on... 
        }
    }

    function resetData() {
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = dataStore.name;
        document.getElementById('imagetitle').innerHTML = dataStore.imagetitle;
        // and so on...
    }
    getInitialData();
    //... then later when you want to reset all the values
    resetData();
}​
```